# Ajax form validation and submission settings seem to be entirely ignored and leaves a blank console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

This is for a popup window to occur (link: http://cdn.moranautoads.com/fh/country/page/15-02-23_coupon-popup/index.html). The validation seems to be completely ignored, and the console leaves me without an error. This code is actually crafted based on the 'jquery.validate.js' example "errors within an element" (within the download file from http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

HTML:

```
            <form action=
            "http://cdn.moranautoads.com/fh/country/page/15-02-23_coupon-popup/form.php"
            class="myForm" id="myForm" method="get" name="myForm" 
            target="slide_form">
                <div id="\'tmg_lock_in\'"></div>

                <table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="">
                            <td align="left"><label>
                            Name</label><input id="Full_Name" name=
                            "Full_Name" type="text"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="">
                            <td align="left"><label>
                            Email</label><input id="Email" name="Email" type="text"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="">
                            <td align="left"><label>
                            Phone</label><input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr style="">
                            <td align="center" colspan="2"><input id=
                            "submit" name="submit" style=
                            "outline:none;border:none;font-family:sans-serif;background:rgb(174,55,36);border-radius:12px;-webkit-border-radius:12px;color: #FFFFFF;cursor: pointer;font-size: 16px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;padding: 14px;text-align: center;border-bottom:5px solid rgb(147,36,12);padding-bottom: 10px;"
                            type="submit" value=
                            "Get Bonus Cash Now"><input name="page" type=
                            "hidden" value="External Slide"><input name=
                            "Vehicle_Type" type="hidden" value=
                            ""><input name="tmg_year" type="hidden" value=
                            ""><input name="tmg_make" type="hidden" value=
                            ""><input name="tmg_model" type="hidden" value=
                            ""><input name="tmg_trim" type="hidden" value=
                            ""><input name="tmg_offer" type="hidden" value=
                            "0"><input name="tmg_stock" type="hidden"
                            value=""><input name="tmg_vin" type="hidden"
                            value=""><input name="tmg_price" type="hidden"
                            value=""><input name="request_type" type=
                            "hidden" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
```

JS:

```
include('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js',
    function() {
        var imported = document.createElement('script');
        imported.src =
            'http://cdn.moranautoads.com/fh/country/page/15-02-23_coupon-popup/jquery.validate.min.js';
        document.head.appendChild(imported);
        $.getScript(
            'http://cdn.moranautoads.com/fh/country/page/15-02-23_coupon-popup/jquery.validate.min.js',
            function() {
                $.validator.setDefaults({
                    submitHandler: function() {
                        alert("submitted!");
                    }
                });
                $().ready(function() {
                    // validate the form when it is submitted
                    var validator = $("#myForm").validate({
                        errorPlacement: function(error,
                            element) {
                            // Append error within linked label
                            $(element).closest(
                                "form").find(
                                "label[for='" +
                                element.attr(
                                    "id") +
                                "']").append(
                                error);
                        },
                        errorElement: "span",
                        rules: {
                            Full_Name: {
                                required: true,
                            },
                            Email: {
                                required: true,
                                email: true,
                            },
                            Phone: {
                                required: true,
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {
                            Full_Name: {
                                required: " (required)",
                                minlength: " (must be at least 3 characters)"
                            },
                            Email: {
                                required: " (required)",
                                minlength: " (must be between 5 and 12 characters)",
                                maxlength: " (must be between 5 and 12 characters)"
                            },
                            Phone: {
                                required: " (required)",
                                minlength: " (must be between 5 and 12 characters)",
                                maxlength: " (must be between 5 and 12 characters)"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $(".cancel").click(function() {
                        validator.resetForm();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: You're missing the `rules:` option to `validate()`. You need that or you need to add appropriate attributes to the input elements.

Comment: @Barmar Edit to add rules, still completely bypasses validation

Comment: Is it doing the "submitted!" alert?

Comment: @Barmar Nope, it is skipping that as well, it basically acts as if the javascript isn't even targeting the form.
A live link is here: http://cdn.moranautoads.com/fh/country/page/15-02-23_coupon-popup/index.html if you wish to see it in action.

Comment: Inspecting your live DOM reveals that you're loading jQuery, then jQuery Validate, then another version of jQuery in the body, then your jQuery scripts and methods.  I'm fairly certain that the second version of jQuery being loaded after the Validate plugin is breaking everything.

Comment: @Sparky sadly, when I remove the the jquery call in the position I need it (above validation), it tells me that jquery is undefined. The first jquery call is a vendor version, which carries edits (for whatever reason).

I don't see where the validate script is called/active twice. I do see it being called, then required for use in the function.

.validate method is listed in:

var validator = $("#myForm").validate({

$.validator.setDefaults({
            submitHandler: function() {
                alert("submitted!");
            }
         });

Comment: I did not say Validate was loaded twice... ***jQuery* is loaded twice**.  I don't know what else to tell you.  But you need to inspect your **live DOM**... you are loading jQuery 1.7 in the `head` from [http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js) and jQuery 1.6.2 in the `body` from [http://rndinteractive.com/scripts/jquery-latest.min.js](http://rndinteractive.com/scripts/jquery-latest.min.js)... you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Sparky Strangely, If I remove either one, it tells me that my jquery is undefined (i have never once had this issue before).. if you have any pointers on how to restore this I appreciate it. If not, I guess it is time to start over.

Comment: I really think you should start over; and you just can't arbitrarily remove _either_ one... in this case, the second one is the issue.  jQuery always needs to load **first** (and not again) before any plugins.

Comment: Alright, will do. Also, I am aware that it needs to load first, I was only mentioning this based on that fact that if I remove the bottom one, it says that jQuery is undefined. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sparky Just wanted to say that I ended up getting it working on the rewrite procedure and everything is working well. Thank you for your input/suggestions.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below if you believe it will help others.  Otherwise, feel free to click the delete link.  Thanks.